# how to start a next activity after clicking on viewpager?

Tags: java, android, xml

**my HomeActivity.java :**

```
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    SlidingImage_Adapter pagerAdapter = new SlidingImage_Adapter(fm);
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
}


private Boolean exit=false;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (exit) {
        finish();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tekan lagi untuk keluar.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        exit = true;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                exit = false;
            }
        }, 3 * 1000);
    }
    ;
}
```

this is for connecting between Homeact and image_model

**my SlidingImage_adapter.java :**

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    ImageModel myFragment = new ImageModel();
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putInt("current_page", arg0+1);
    myFragment.setArguments(data);
    return myFragment;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Page_Count;
}
```

this is to take the pict from .xml that i make (layout1.xml, layout2.xml, etc)

**my Image_Model.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle data = getArguments();
    mCurrentPage = data.getInt("current_page", 0);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = null;
    if (mCurrentPage == 1) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, container, false);
    } else if (mCurrentPage == 2) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2, container, false);
    } else if (mCurrentPage == 3) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout3, container, false);
    }
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Inside your *Image_Model.java***

```
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle data = getArguments();
        mCurrentPage = data.getInt("current_page", 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = null;
        if (mCurrentPage == 1) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, container, false);
        } else if (mCurrentPage == 2) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2, container, false);
        } else if (mCurrentPage == 3) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout3, container, false);
        }
       v.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
Intent i=new Intent(getContext(), YouActivity.class);
getContext.startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: nothing work on my project :( 
when i run my app, and clickin my viewpager one click or double click there's nothin happen. not going to my ListActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Set viewPager.clicable = true; on xml file or dynamically if you want and use onClickListener method on viewpager.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    pager.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i=new Intent(getContext(), YouActivity.class);
        getContext.startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```